# Open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)?

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, ioexception, android-storage

```
new File(System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + "/foo/", "bar.txt").createNewFile()
```

That line of code should have created a file in directory foo in the sd card (sd card is mounted). However `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")` returns `"/storage/sdcard1"`. It should work fine, only that that first like of code that should create a file throws

```
android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

note: a subclass of `IOException`

Reading using `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")` works fine, however, all means of writing will fail with the same exception.

This is easily avoided by using `"/sdcard/"` but that method is unreliable as not all manufacturers would place a sdcard shortcut in root.

Is there a way to get around this reliably?

Comment: Have you added Permission to write external storage in manifest?

Comment: Fyi I want a feature where downloads (app feature) may be placed in the internal or sd card as a setting, and I fell here.

Comment: Yes @IntsabHaider, yes I have.

Answer (score 0):

> That line of code should have created a file in directory foo in the sd card (sd card is mounted).

Not on any device manufactured in the past four years or so. It did not work reliably before then either, as there is no requirement for such an environment variable to exist and point to anywhere that you can use.

> Reading using System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") works fine

If by "reading" you mean "reading from a filesystem location pointed to by that undocumented, unsupported environment variable", then it only works on buggy devices that happen to publish a semi-useful value in that undocumented, unsupported environment variable.

> This is easily avoided by using "/sdcard/" but that method is unreliable as not all manufacturers would place a sdcard shortcut in root.

It also does not point to an SD card.

> Is there a way to get around this reliably?

You have no ability to write to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

The simplest places to write to on removable storage are in the locations supplied by the `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()` methods on a `Context`. If those return 2+ locations, the second and subsequent ones are on removable storage, and you have full read/write access to them.

Comment: Those do work, however, is there any better way to easily get the root folder of the sd card. I feel like I'm asking too much but if anyone knows, please share your knowledge. Right now, I'll use `getExternalCacheDirs()[1].getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile()`. Thanks @CommonsWare.

Comment: @iBlueDust: That is not going to be reliable, and even if it was, you are not supposed to be able to read or write that location. There is no way to get to the root folder, for the simple reason that such a folder is useless to you. What Google would like you to use is the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`), rather than working with any filesystems directly.